# Loading HTML containing UTF-8 characters with Jsoup: Works for some websites, but not for others?

Tags: java, html, http, utf-8, jsoup

I have a strange issue with Jsoup: I use this function to retrieve the UTF-8 encoded HTML from a website:

```
public static Document getDocument(String url) {

        Document doc = null;

        try {

            doc = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url).openStream(), "UTF-8", url);
            doc.outputSettings().charset("UTF-8"); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        return doc;
    }
```

Now I take some url-String and do this to print out the html:

```
System.out.println(getDocument(url).body().html());
```

I tried this for different websites containing russian characters and it is really confusing: For some websites it works (the html looks fine), for others all russian characters are replaced by �. But the code I use is exactly the same in both cases!
For example with "https://mail.ru/" it works, but with "http://monetki.su/" it doesn't (all russian characters replaced by �)! How can this depend on the website?

Thanks and greetings,
Daniel

Comment: What makes you think every web site serves its content with the UTF-8 encoding?  That second one uses windows-1251.

Comment: Ah, you're right, thanks!